# Modal Onclick Visibility Not Working As Intended

Tags: javascript, html, css

My modal below isn't working but I'm not experienced enough to figure why. I'm trying to hide my modal using visibility: hidden, then changing to visibility: visible onclick.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="modalSignin"></div>

     <div class="authBtns" onclick="modalLogin()">
          <a href="#" id="loginBtn">Login</a>
          <a href="#" id="regBtn">Register</a>
     </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .modalSignin {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: black;
        min-width: 40%;
        min-height: 400px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
   function modalLogin() {
        var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modalSignin");
         modal.style.visibility = "visible";
    };
```

Please see above code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName`  returns a elements, like Array

use `querySelector` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

```js
function modalLogin() {
    var modal = document.querySelector("modalSignin");
    modal.style.visibility = "visible";
};
```